# 3-Dimentional array

Tags: 3d

I'm good in 2-D array which is the regular array that has rows and columns, but I have to deal with the 3D array and I can't imagine it, I tried searching for it but with no clue. Any big example of 3D array? Anything through it make it clear for me? Thanks,

Comment: You could think of an Excel workbook with multiple spreadsheets.  Each sheet could be for a different year.  On each sheet, the Columns could represent months.  Rows could represent day of the month.  And then, in the cells you could put, say, the daily high temperature.  T(1998,7,4)=101

Answer (score 1):

You can look at them as a sequence of matrices, with the third coordinate being the index of the sequence.

If you want a practical example, think of e.g. a matrix representing the coordinates of three planets in space. Suppose you look at the evolution of the system over time, and require only one update every second. Then you have a sequence of matrices and the third coordinate represents time.